# Undefined reference to function that is already defined in my header file

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-reference

I have three files, `posl.h`, `state.c` and `main.c`. What I plan on doing is adding functions that are used throughout the project in `posl.h`, and then I call it to test the function with `main.c`, and then make the function in `state.c`. The problem I am having is that I keep getting an error of `undefined reference to init_poslState()` even though I have it defined in `posl.h`

main.c

```
#include <posl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pState poslState = init_poslState();
    return 0;
}
```

posl.h

```
#ifndef POSL_LANGUAGE_H
#define POSL_LANGUAGE_H

#define POSL_MAJOR_VERSION 1
#define POSL_MINOR_VERSION 0
#define POSL_RELEASE_VERSION 0

// State
typedef struct POSL_STATE {
    // ...
} pState;
pState init_poslState();
void free_poslState(pState poslState);

#endif
```

state.c

```
#include "state.h"
#include <posl.h>

pState init_poslState() {
    pState newState;
    return newState;
}
```

Makefile

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -I./include
CC=gcc $(CFLAGS)
CORE_O_FILES=./src/Core/lexer.o ./src/Core/parser.o ./src/Core/state.o
CLI_O_FILES=
O_FILES=$(CORE_O_FILES)

# Making CLI Tool
posl: $(CLI_O_FILES) libposl.a ./src/CLI/main.c
    $(CC) -o posl -L./ -lposl ./src/CLI/main.c $(CLI_O_FILES)

# Making Library
libposl.a: $(O_FILES) ./include/posl.h
    ar rcs libposl.a $^


# Core Files
./src/Core/lexer.o: ./src/Core/lexer.c ./src/Core/lexer.h
    $(CC) -o $@ -c ./src/Core/lexer.c
./src/Core/parser.o: ./src/Core/parser.c ./src/Core/parser.h
    $(CC) -o $@ -c ./src/Core/parser.c
./src/Core/state.o: ./src/Core/state.c ./src/Core/state.h
    $(CC) -o $@ -c ./src/Core/state.c

# PHONY List

.PHONY: all
all:
    make update-libs
    make libposl.a
    make posl
    make pcc

# Post-Compile Clean
.PHONY: pcc
pcc:
    rm -rf ./src/Core/*.o
    rm -rf ./src/CLI/*.o

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    make pcc
    rm -rf ./libposl.a ./posl*
```

Comment: That's a declaration, but not a definition. You are showing no definition (i.e. a declaration with a function body). Where is it?

Comment: @user17732522 my bad, i added it into the question

Comment: Order of `-l` flags matters. They belong after the source files in the linker invocation.

Answer (score 1):

The order of compiler and (especially) linker options is significant.  With this command ...

> ```
>     $(CC) -o posl -L./ -lposl ./src/CLI/main.c $(CLI_O_FILES)
> ```

... the linker will not attempt to resolve any function references from `main.c` against functions in libposl.a.  It will look only to objects and libraries appearing *after* `main.c` on the command line.

Therefore, rewrite that recipe to

```
     $(CC) -o posl -L. ./src/CLI/main.c $(CLI_O_FILES) -lposl
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, @user17732522 answered my question. I had the `-l` flag messed up, and it wasn't after my source files. ~Thank you guys!~